# Как наградить репутацией участника за ответ, помимо голоса?

Tags: поддержка

Иногда возникает желание накинуть Участнику за ответ побольше репутации (естественно из своей, как за конкурсы), помимо единственного голоса. Это возможно?

Comment: Плюс, принятие ответ (если автор), конкурс. Вроде бы больше ничего нет - торговли, бартера, покупки, кражи, вымогательства репы нет.

Comment: Bounty можно назначить и наградить понравившийся ответ.

Comment: Если у участника в профиле указана какая-то ссылка на любой донат (PayPal, WebMoney и т.д.), то также можете участника отблагодарить материально.